# MySQL delete after input date

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL code where I insert the date when it's sent and the input days which can be from 1 do 7. How can I make MySQL to delete a row after the input days?

Ex: I created a product on 22.03.2021 at 3:54 PM and the input of days to expire is 6. I want to delete the product after exactly 6 days.

```
$date = date("y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hours'));


$sql = "INSERT INTO products (produs, autor, data, detalii, price, poze, dayss) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['nume'], $_SESSION['nickname'], $date, $_POST['details'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['poze'], $_POST['dayss']]);
```

Comment: First you should do is make sure that the dates are stored correctly. The column you store them in should be of the type "datetime", which requires it to have the format: `Y-m-d H:i:is` while you're storing them as `y-m-d H:i:s` (capital Y = four digits and a lower y = two digits). Are you storing the dates as varchar?

Comment: We're glad to help you sort out the specifics if you run into any issues with your existing code, but we're not as keen to write your code for you. If you have tried something, please post the attempt and explain what happens. If you haven't tried anything, please do some research and make some attempt first.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM products WHERE DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL dayys DAY) < NOW()`

You could run this query every time a new product is inserted, or via a scheduled job that runs each day.

Comment: is there a way to test this? I mean I tried to test it by editing the date and put it in the past, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO products (produs, autor, data, detalii, price, poze, dayss) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['nume'], $_SESSION['nickname'], $date, $_POST['details'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['poze'], $_POST['dayss']]);

$_SESSION['info'] = 1337;
header('location: admin.php');

$sql= "DELETE FROM products WHERE DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL dayys DAY) < NOW()" 

this is how I inserted it into the code.

Comment: You need to execute the query.  According to the above you are just assigning it to the variable `$sql`

Comment: Made it work but it is deleting everything, not only the expired ones.

Comment: Try changing it to a select statement, and see what it returns, and figure out where it is going wrong: `SELECT produs, data, dayys, DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL dayys DAY) AS deletion_date FROM products WHERE DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL dayys DAY) < NOW()`  And as someone else mentioned, your date format is wrong, `y-m-d H:i:s` should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`